# Append list of data object to serialized form

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I want to map the list of data object with serialize form data my backend is .Net and I have a Model class to map the parameter

Here is my jQuery object

```
var MultiAssignGarageCampaign = [];

    var obj = {};

    obj.GarageID = 15;
    obj.CampaignID = 8;

    MultiAssignGarageCampaign.push(obj);
```

Here is my ajax request

```
var data = {
  'MultiAssignGarageCampaign' : MultiAssignGarageCampaign
};

data = $form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(data);

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Booking/Create',
    data: data ,         
    dataType: 'json'

}).done(function () {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

Here is my backend Model

```
public class BookingViewModel
    {

public IList<GeneralCampaign> MultiAssignGarageCampaign { get; set; } 

}
```

When I hard code the query like this it works

```
//data = $("#frmCreateBooking").serialize() + '&MultiAssignGarageCampaign[0].GarageID=15&MultiAssignGarageCampaign[0].CampaignID=8';
```

Comment: Don't you need to serialize `MultiAssignGarageCampaign` too?

Comment: Your object has to be in a special format. `If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray()`. Check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

Comment: How does your server action method parameter looks like ? What is in your form ?

Comment: Do you need uriencoded data? Is your form the same as pointed from the working selector? What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but you are econding data twice:

1. first using jQuery `param`
2. second using jQuery `ajax`

I think it will work fine by decode the serialized data gotten from jQuery `param` like:

```
data = $form.serialize() + '&' + decodeURIComponent($.param(data));
```

Comment: its creating the list of object from backend side but data are not mapped with the object  :(
the issue is it creating the parameter like this 
MultiAssignGarageCampaign[0][GarageID]=44&

it should be 
MultiAssignGarageCampaign[0].[GarageID]=44&

to map the data